# Футболка это специальная T-shirt для игры в футбол?

Tags: значения

Или это есть просто название верхней летней одежды?

You can answer in English.

Comment: Just a minor correction - верхняя одежда is something like a coat or jacket. And another interesting fact for you. Бейсболка in Russian is used to refer to any hat that looks like baseball cap (trucker cap, all those kinds), but of course no-one thinks actually of baseball game when they mean this kind of cap. A similar evolution of the word I guess. Strangely enough, people tend to use smth. like футбольная форма if they mean sports of football.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не стоит воспринимать название так буквально, футболка это просто t-shirt а не конкретно форма для спортивных футбольных команд или её членов.

Answer (score 4):

Когда t-shirt впервые появилась в СССР, ею первой начали пользоваться именно футболисты, потому она и получила такое название. Но в итоге "футболка" просто название данной одежды в русском языке и не имеет никакого отношения к тому, кто ей пользуется.